DefaultDllImportSearchPathsAttribute behaviour for LibraryImportAttribute
Migrating from the DllImportAttribute to the LibraryImportAttribute like described in Source generation for platform invokes, I've stumbled over the DefaultDllImportSearchPathsAttribute, which specifies the paths that are used to search for DLLs.
Assuming I have the following DLL import,
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[DefaultDllImportSearchPaths(DllImportSearchPath.System32)]
private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk);

updated to
[LibraryImport("user32.dll")]
[DefaultDllImportSearchPaths(DllImportSearchPath.System32)]
private static partial bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk);

, will the search path also be handled by the LibraryImportAttribute as done before?

Yes, something you can see with a decompiler (like ILSpy).  The source generator hoists the DefaultDllImportSearchPaths attribute into a method with a DllImport attribute.  You should not do this for winapi dlls, the OS needs to figure out by itself to load the dll from either system32 or syswow64.  Also note the new rules for marshaling bool.  You'd consider using this for platform targets that require AOT, like iOS.

If you don't specify the DefaultDllImportSearchPaths attribute for a winapi DLL, e.g. kernel32.dll, the CA5392 warning is produced (verified on .NET 8).  @HansPassant Thoughts?

As already stated in the comments, the answer is yes,
DefaultDllImportSearchPaths will be handled by the LibraryImport as well.
It can be seen in the .NET source code where LibraryImportGenerator.cs handles the DllImportSearchPathsAttribute.
Decompiling and testing it with some minimal sample executable confirms this as well.
